# Ruby On Rails 3.2.13 - Using Different Gemsets For Rails Applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, gemset

I currently have several Rails applications running version 3.2.13 that use Ruby 1.9.3.  I plan to eventually upgrade my current applications to Rails 4.0 then upgrade Ruby to 2.0.  I need to time the conversion to Ruby 2.0 carefully since from my understanding Phusion Passenger will only handle one version of Ruby without some nose bleeding solutions which I do not plan to attempt to implement at this point.

I currently use one gemset for all my Rails applications.  I would like to convert my Rails applications one by one from 3.2.13 to the current version of Rails 4.0 at some point.  When I have tried to update one of my applications to a newer version of Rails I was told I had to do a update rails command.

What I want to do is to be able to run some of my applications using Rails 3.2.13 and others using Rails 4.0 until I am sure they will all run properly under Rails 4.0.  Once I do this I will review the differences between Ruby 1.9.3 (if any) and upgrade all of them to use Rails 2.0.  At this point I understand that I would just create the gemset for 2.0.0 or whatever the latest stable version of Ruby 2 is.

I have done web searches and checked the RVM website.  I understand how the gemsets are assigned to the version of Ruby you want to run.  However I'm not seeing anything about using gemsets with the same version of Ruby but using different versions of Rails or other combinations of gems on the same machine for different applications.  Can this be done?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The [RVM guides](https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics/) explain exactly what you're talking about in the very first example.

Comment: That explained how to create the different gemsets for different versions of Rails but it does not explain how to identify which gemset to use for each application.  Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Take a closer look! ;)

First, create a new gemset with a name corresponding to your project
https://rvm.io/gemsets/creating/
ex: `rvm gemset create project_name`

Then create/edit .rvmrc file in project directory: `rvm use 1.9.3@project_name`

One pitfall is that if you execute following commands

```
cd some_project
cd ../other_project
```

and other_project doesn't have gemset specified you'll stay in some_project gemset. To avoid that you can create .rvmrc file with default gemset in your "projects" directory (if you have one)

Comment: I am not currently using .rvmrc in my projects.  This may explain something else I just found.  My attempt was to use one gemset for all my Rails applications but after listing the gemsets I see that I had inadvertently created other ones.  It looks like my gemsets are getting out of control.  I may try another option here.

Comment: You can also take a look at rbenv. Personally I have completely different approach, since all my apps are Ruby 1.9.3.
I told bundler to install gems in project_dir/.gems so for each project I have gem separation by default. See https://github.com/hajder/bootstrap-ruby-on-your-mac however it's not complete

Answer (score 1):

```
Project Folder
|___Gemfile
|__.ruby-gemset
|__.ruby-version

 Gemfile with all the required gems mention in your project folder
.ruby-gemset should have gem set name like sample-gemset
.ruby-version file should have specific ruby version (e.g 2.0)

 rvm gemset list
```

it will show gem set created with **sample-gemset** and do the

> bundle install

which will install all the specific gems for this project under sample-gemset,
same you can do for other project to create other gem set, in this way you can maintain different rails/gems and ruby version for different projects with rvm.

Answer (score 0):

Your Gemfile.lock nails down which version of every gem you use - you don't need to worry about gemsets.

`bundle install` will always install the correct versions and your app will always use the versions in Gemfile.lock, even if there are other versions floating around

Comment: I prefer, like yourself, to just use bundler to manage my gems, but it does mean having to use `bundle exec` in the case you have multiple versions of gems floating around -- worth mentioning.

Comment: Just to clarify: To update one of my applications to use Rails 4.0 is all I have to do is change the Rails version in my Gemfile along with adding the Ruby version number then do a bundle exec?  I want to make sure that this will allow me to run Rails 3.2.13 and Rails 4.0 in different applications.

Comment: `bundle install` / `bundle update` to update what is in your bundle but otherwise yes. bundle exec is for when you want to  run executables from gems (eg bundle exec rails g migration Foo)

Comment: `bundle exec rails s`, `bundle exec rake ...` etc. This is because otherwise you're not running the executables in the context of your bundle, so it'll use the most recent gem in your system and complain when it doesn't match your Gemfile.